# Meteor and manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, manifest

I would like add a `manifest.json` on Meteor for open my website on 'standalone'. So i've creat my [app-manifest.json](http://stephane-richin.fr/app-manifest.json) on my /public/ folder, but when i test my website from Google, i do not have the message by Chrome for install my App offline.

I've add this :

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/app-manifest.json?v=kjppgrg225grspg">
```

But no result.

Do you have any idea why the message isn't display ? My app-manifest file is correct so ? You can see this on [my webiste](http://stephane-richin.fr) using MeteorJS.

Thank you !

Comment: I visited your website on my android and it seems manifest is working. But I'm having trouble with mine. How did you get it working? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Have you successfully installed the app meteor ?

Comment: Somehow I managed to make my manifest to work..it was probably some invalid key. Thanks!

Comment: I would be interested to know how you did it. For my part, it does not seem to work. Could you contact me?

Comment: Stéphane. I'm really sorry but I seemed to get your original question wrong! My problem was making my webapp look like a standalone on my phone. Regarding your original question: I've never being able to make show a message to install my app offline. Sorry :(